# Two mod-rewrite rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-routing

I need two conditional rules. Background:

```
http://www.domain.com/.htaccess
http://www.domain.com/index.php
http://www.domain.com/admin/index.php
```

I have both re-write rules:

```
ROOT:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1.php?%1 [L]

ADMIN:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+?)/([a-z]+?)/(.*)$ index.php?model=$1&view=$2¶ms=$3 [L,NS]
```

I need to somehow have only the one .htaccess file on the root level use both rules but the ADMIN rules only apply when url `http://www.domain.com/admin/foo/bar/something/else` and the ROOT rule applies to `http://www.domain.com/foo/bar/something/else`.

Thank you in advance, I have killed an entire day trying to do this and when one works the other gives me a "Not Found" page error.

Kris

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992054/subfolders-and-mod-rewrite

Comment: jitter: can you answer my question then please? Why post a comment if it isn't constructive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# /admin/ rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ admin/index.php?model=$1&view=$2&params=$3 [L,NS]
RewriteRule ^admin/ - [L]

# other rules
RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag (*query string append*) replace the `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)` directives.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1.php?%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z]+?)/([a-z]+?)/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?model=$1&view=$2&params=$3 [L,NS]
```

Comment: You might want to add comments or a paragraph explaining your Conditions.

Comment: chaos: thank you for your quick response.  It doesn't seem to be working though...? I even tried changing a few things and still no luck :(